# Вставить значения GET-параметров из адресной строки в input формы

Tags: javascript, php, html

На странице есть форма с полями: **ticket_id**, **rating** и **comment**.

url страницы имеет вид ***https://site.com/event.html?ticket=13144&rating=1&comment=test***

Подскажите плиз, есть ли возможность вытащить данные из url и вставить их в форму?

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="ticket_id" value="<?=$_GET['ticket'];?>">
<input type="text" name="rating" value="<?=$_GET['rating'];?>">
<input type="text" name="comment" value="<?=$_GET['comment'];?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, пойду пробовать)

Comment: Массив `$_GET`, а не `$GET`.

Comment: Еще нужно бы `htmlspecialchars`, иначе можно легко сделать XSS атаку)

Comment: не сработало. просто в самом поле внутри показывается выражение <?=$_GET['ticket'];?>

Comment: Да, я извиняюсь забыл про $_GET

Comment: Вот так выглядит: <input type="text" name="ticket_id" value="<?=$_GET['ticket'];?>">, а в поле в итоге написано само выражение <?=$_GET['ticket'];?>, а не значение параметра